# Scroll text reading it from .txt file

Tags: php, html, scroll, marquee

I have a .txt file, which contains a data. The data keeps changing. I want to create a marquee which scrolls text from bottom to top with a specified text size.

So, the marquee needs to read a .txt file and transfer that text to marquee. I'm using HTML files, can also use PHP.

Can anyone provide me the code? I'm new to this.

Comment: show the code you had tried

Comment: You could search at google for "reading text from file php" and you'd have found plenty of answers to start with. Even less complicated ones than provided in the answers here. And: You would've learned something!

Comment: here is the [project]: http://files.videohelp.com/u/210313/project.zip

Answer (score 1):

You can stream content of a.txt by using [stream_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php). Also read my comments on code carefully;

**PHP:** `content.php`

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['tail'])) {
  session_start();
  $handle = fopen('a.txt', 'r');// I assume, a.txt is in the same path with content.php
  if (isset($_SESSION['offset'])) {
    $data = stream_get_contents($handle, -1, $_SESSION['offset']);// Second parameter is the size of text you will read on each request
    echo nl2br($data);
  } else {
    fseek($handle, 0, SEEK_END);
    $_SESSION['offset'] = ftell($handle);
  } 
  exit();
} 
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script><!-- give corrected jquery path -->
  <script>
  setInterval(function(){get_contents();}, 10000);
  function get_contents() {
    $.get('content.php?tail', function(data) {
        $('#contents').append(data);
      });
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="contents">Loading...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i already have a php file to generate txt file. should i specifically use content.php

Comment: No, you can use your own php but in my example I have used stream_get_contents and saved offset in session. Be sure that you are using that

Comment: i think i dont want to any php to generate txt file. What i'm trying is just marquee (scroll bottom to top) the text using the text present inside *.txt file.

Comment: I am not generating, reading text file and send to html realtime

Comment: okay... now. i have an *.txt file. I created a content.php, change the a.txt to *.txt. After that should i change 'Offset' to a value? After doing this, i copy pasted the html code in an existing html file.

Comment: i checked every other way i can... there should be something wrong with the html code.

Comment: Could you please check with firebug, is it correctly makes ajax call and getting response?

Comment: hmmm. checked with firefox. the version of jquery.js might be different. Will that affect?

Comment: Nope,  ajax works with almost every version. Any error on firebug?

Comment: can you make an html file with the above marque working and upload it here. I may be wrong in this. just use an txt file name file.txt (txt contains marquee text).

Comment: Fixed and uploaded here http://www.rapidfileshare.net/n0zckfkqtsa1/project.zip.html. You have errors on your php file

Comment: is not working yet. is it only me who has that problem, or everyone else?

Comment: Could you please provide some error please? How can I know which error occurs. Check firebug console and php error log if any error occurs

Comment: When i open the 22.html file. It just displays ' Loading... ' and there is no marquee happening.

Answer (score -1):

You may use the 'stream' method, or a simpler 'include' method. The 'include' method loads the data upon page load, and only updates when refreshed.

```
<?php include "textFile.txt";?>
```

You can change the file path between the quotation marks to point to the path your text file is at. Other path examples:

```
//File located in the site root, or topmost level of the site:
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/textFile.txt";?>
//File located one folder deeper than the file this code was written in:
<?php include "resources/textFile.txt";?>
```

This may be a large security risk, depending on the content in the .txt file and how the file gets updated. If this text file is updated with a script on your own site, and the only people who have access to the site are people you trust, then it should be fine (well, if people you don't trust have access, then I'd be more concerned about that!).

Comment: This works, but as the txt-file is included here as real PHP code is, this creates a security-leak! If the txt-file now would contain some PHP code, this get's executed. Use the method `http://php.net/file_get_contents` instead and print the response of that method!

Comment: I completely forgot about that! Apologies.

Comment: correct that and I'll give you a vote-up :) But please keep the old answer, just strike it through.

Comment: I'm going to keep the answer as is, but add the bit about the security issue. If the text file is updated by a script on his own site, made by himself etc, there shouldn't be any problems as far as I can tell. If it's all internal, and you trust and know what it's all doing, then you should have control. If someone accesses your server, a little 'include' code will be nothing compared to other potential damage.

Comment: i expected a much more detailed answer.

Comment: well, can please upload complete html file code? i think this is what i'm looking for.